# Plotting 3 times of a page with plots of proportional length in R

Tags: r

How can I use the `heatmap.2` function from `gplots` to generate 3 heatmaps on the same page where each heatmap has the same row width such that the length of the page for each heatmap is proportional to its number of rows?

My incorrect attempt with some dummy data is below. I think part of the problem is that the `heatmap.2` function starts a new plot, which means that `layout` doesn't help.

```
gs <- paste("GS",sample(10),sep="_")
mat1 <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=10, ncol=10, dimnames=list(sample.int(10000,10),gs ))
mat2 <- matrix(rnorm(150), nrow=15, ncol=10, dimnames=list(sample.int(10000,15),gs ))
mat3 <- matrix(rnorm(200), nrow=20, ncol=10, dimnames=list(sample.int(10000,20),gs ))

nf <- layout(matrix(c(1,2,3),3,1), widths = lcm(5), heights = lcm(5), TRUE)
layout.show(nf)

library(gplots)
heatmap.2(mat1, Rowv=F, Colv=F,col=greenred(200), scale="row",
          key=TRUE, symkey=FALSE, density.info="none", trace="none", dendrogram="none",
          labCol=colnames(mat1), labRow=rownames(mat1), keysize=0.8)
heatmap.2(mat2, Rowv=F, Colv=F,col=greenred(200), scale="row",
          key=TRUE, symkey=FALSE, density.info="none", trace="none", dendrogram="none",
          labCol=colnames(mat2), labRow=rownames(mat2), keysize=0.8)par(mar = c(3,0,1,1))
heatmap.2(mat3, Rowv=F, Colv=F,col=greenred(200), scale="row",
          key=TRUE, symkey=FALSE, density.info="none", trace="none", dendrogram="none",
          labCol=colnames(mat3), labRow=rownames(mat3), keysize=0.8)
```

Comment: That's your problem all right. `heatmap.2 uses `layout` itself, which overrides your specification.

Comment: Anyway to do it with the `grid` package?

Comment: I would have looked at the gridBase package.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is No you can't use `layout` in conjunction with `heatmap.2`.

from `?heatmap.2` it is explicit:

> heatmap.2() uses layout and draws the image in the lower right corner
>   of a 2x2 layout. Consequentially, it can not be used in a multi
>   column/row layout, i.e., when par(mfrow= *) or (mfcol= *) has been
>   called.

You can use `image` here with `axis` since you don't want need to plot dendrogram.

```
library(gplots)

 heatmap3 <- function(mat1){
  image(mat1, Rowv=F, Colv=F,col=greenred(200), scale="row",
        key=TRUE, xlab=colnames(mat1), ylab=rownames(mat1), keysize=0.8)
  axis(1, at = seq(0, 1, length.out = dim(mat1)[1]), labels = gs, 
       las = 2)
  axis(2, at = seq(0, 1, length.out = dim(mat1)[1]), labels = gs, 
       las = 2)
  }
nf <- layout(matrix(c(1,2,3),3,1), widths = lcm(5), heights = lcm(5), TRUE)
heatmap3(mat1)
heatmap3(mat2)
heatmap3(mat3)
```

[image]

Comment: How about for the case where each matrix has a different number of rows? how can I maintain the width of each row with `layout` and `image`?

Comment: I've also realized there's one big problem with using `image`: in `heatmap.2` you can scale by row so that colors are standardized within the row. `image` seems to do this for the whole matrix rather than by row.